# Using Openlog from ssjs. what should 'this' be?

Tags: logging, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am reading from the documentation on openlog:

> Because Server-Side JavaScript Script Libraries have no context for
>   which component called them, you will not be able to use this to pass
>   the component to OpenLog. Instead, if you wish to identify which
>   component called the code, you need to pass the component into your
>   SSJS function as a parameter.

https://wiki.openntf.org/display/XOL/Using+from+SSJS+Script+Libraries

So I have a link which calls a SSJS function that resides in a script library:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="#{obj.name}" rendered="#{obj.internal eq '3'}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dlgAssessment"> <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:openDialogAssessment(this);}]]></xp:this.action> </xp:eventHandler> </xp:link>
```

The function registers failures to openlog as followed:

```
function openDialogAssessment(component){
    try {       
        try{
           assessmentBean.removeAssessment("assessment");
        }catch(e){
            openLogBean.addError(e,component);
        }
//... more code
}
```

If I look at the log result in openlog I read:

> null - Developer has passed 'this' directly from an SSJS function in
>   Script Library /proposal.jss. Please note, SSJS Script Libraries have
>   no context for components. You must pass the relevant component into
>   your SSJS function as a parameter.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I could pass the component to the function correctly?

Comment: Ferry is spot on. `this` is always the xp/xe/xc XML tag surrounding the code. I won't post an answer, instead Ferry should move his comment to an answer so he can get the credit for answering it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context 'this' is the eventHandler. An eventHandler is not a UIComponent. You should pass 'this.getParent()' (the link) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Ferry stated, this refers to a component, not the function. therefor the component should be provided to the ssjs function e.g. this.getParent().